# Detecting state of a button when in parallel with LED

Tags: arduino

I am using an Arduino to try to update an old lighting system in my house. The previous solution was a 20-30 year old Lutron Lumaster system. However, it was struck by lightning last summer and is no longer in commission.

Part of the lighting system are several low voltage switches distributed around the house. Each switch contains an LED (this indicates if the overhead lights for that switch are on or not) and a push button.

Because I couldn't find much info about this system online, I have been trying to reverse engineer how it works to put an Arduino in its place.

What I need to do is:

1. Be able to toggle the LED in the wall plate on and off.
2. Detect if the button in the wall plate is pushed or not.

The only issue is, the button and the switch are wired in parallel. Meaning at the electrical panel there are two wires. One marked "COM" and one marked "A". If you put a ohm meter across COM and A, you'll find pushing the button toggles it from something like 500K Ohms to 10K Ohms. Also, if you were to put 12V across COM and A (with + on COM) you would light the LED.

Is there a way to both drive the LED and detect the button push? I can figure out how to do or the other, but not both at the same time. Not entirely sure its possible.

Comment: What color is the LED? How much current does it draw on 12V with the pushbutton off, and how much with the button on? Will the LED light on lower voltage (eg. 5V)?

Comment: look through these documents ... http://www.freepatentsonline.com/D344264.html

Comment: Should "the button and the switch are wired in parallel" read "the button and the **LED** are wired in parallel"?

Comment: Can you check if the push-button is normally open (NO) or normally closed (NC)?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know how the switch is wired. You can open it to check what is inside, or guess through measurements. It could be like this, this schematic shows several possibilities.

[image: schematic]

The button could be across the LED (wire labeled 2 on schematic) or across a LED+resistor in series (labeled 1) and there could be a resistor R2 in series with the whole thing, or maybe not.

To investigate this, don't use a ohmmeter as this will give bogus measurements across a diode like a LED. Instead you can power the switch from a +12V or +5V power supply with a resistor in series (say, 1k). Then measure voltage across the switch when the button is not pressed, and when the button is pressed.

When the button is not pressed you'll have a LED in series with a resistor, so by using two supply voltages (+12 and +5) and knowing the LED color (thus its forward voltage) you can determine the series resistor value. Then when pressing the button and measuring the voltage across the switch, you can determine how the button is wired. If foltage drops ot near zero then it will be option "1" in schematic above and no R2.

After you do this you can determine whether you'll need to use ADC to sample your voltage. The ideal solution would be to have a clearly defined logic level, but that will depend on the way the switch is wired. So, please update the question when you have more info.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch/LED configuration to light the LED when the switch is 'on'. In this case the LED is not across the switch.

[image]

2. Switch/LED configuration to light the LED when the switch is 'off'. In this case the LED is across the switch.

[image]

LED current limiting resistors are not shown.